# ionic http POST not working on server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I have a big trouble since 2 days, my app previously worked everywhere with the same code, now I get this error if I run the `ionic serve` command and make a POST request:

```
OPTIONS https://www.example.com/file.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE(anonymous function) @
ionic.bundle.js:16185sendReq @
ionic.bundle.js:15979status.$get.serverRequest @
ionic.bundle.js:15712deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback @
ionic.bundle.js:19197deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback @
ionic.bundle.js:19197(anonymous function) @
ionic.bundle.js:19283promises.$get.Scope.$eval @
ionic.bundle.js:20326promises.$get.Scope.$digest @
ionic.bundle.js:20138promises.$get.Scope.$apply @
ionic.bundle.js:20430(anonymous function) @
ionic.bundle.js:26763(anonymous function) @
ionic.bundle.js:10478forEach @ ionic.bundle.js:7950eventHandler @
ionic.bundle.js:10477
```

if I try to run the app on the iPhone, iPhone simulator, android devices everything works well. I used chrome for MAC OSX and Windows with CORS addon enabled.
If I switch to a development server (that is not https but http only http://dev.example.com/file.php  ) I get the same error also in all devices but Android.
I tried to enable CORS in my apache server by editing the `.htaccess` file by adding this:  `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` and it doesn't solve anything.  Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is definitely a CORS problem, I temporarily solved (I can develop now on the browser) by switching to safari, went to Develop > Disable Cross Origin - Restrictions. Apparently seems that CORS add-on on chrome is failing to disable CORS restrictions. I hope I can help other devs

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$response = array(
    'LoginResult' => array(
      'Authorized' => TRUE,
      'FormOpen' => TRUE,
    ),
  );

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Here is some working PHP code (server side) I use for my Ionic application.

```
if (authObject == undefined) {
  authObject = {};
}

$http({
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      method: "POST",
      url: LoginUrl,
      data: authObject
    }).success(function (data) {
      if (data.LoginResult && data.LoginResult.Authorized) {
        // The login was successfull, save the authObject.
        $localStorage.currentUser = authObject;

        // deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + authObject.UserName + '!');
      }
      else {
        // deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
      }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // deferred.reject(data, status);
    });
```

And here is the Ionic call.

Hope it helps, don't really know if you have access to the server side.